# jquery bind change event to input when value updated through jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an input box on a form and I want to fire an event when the value of that input changes.  The value is typically changed through some other jQuery function and the `.change()` event does not appear to be triggered when this happens.

How can I make this possible?

Comment: It should work buddy, unless for first attempt when you write something into the test box.

Answer (score 3):

You need to fire the change event manually

Ex:

```
$('<selector>').val('<value>').trigger('change')
```

Comment: But my script does not have any other relation to the other script that is triggering the change

Comment: @MartyWallace Then there isn't much you can do, but it doesn't make sense for that to be a problem. There's no reason you can't add .change() to it after calling `.val(value)`, it's still decoupled from whatever is listening for that change event.

Comment: @MartyWallace in that case I think you are out of luck

Comment: So it is not possible to monitor a form input for changes?  I mean, i would have thought that some event would be fired regardless of how the input is value is changed?

Comment: @MartyWallace Sure, it's possible, but you have to trigger said event yourself.

Comment: Oh my, i find that unbelievable!

Comment: Why? it's no different than doing `$(element).prop("foo","bar")` which also doesn't trigger a change event. All you're doing is updating a property. Updating properties don't result in events.

Answer (score 1):

**Use that**

> $("element").trigger("change");